# Javascript : Selenium WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

For testing,
I have a directory structure like this :
 
  custom
  lib
  tests
  pages
Every JavaScript function written in the 'custom' directory can be accessed by the 'test' directory by a "browser" object.
This is done by the "testutils.js" file in the lib directory.
Likewise,
 Is it possible to retrieve the JavaScript functions in the 'pages' directory can be accessed by the 'test' directory by the path "browser.pages.function-name()"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to implement the PageObject pattern with WebdriverIO. You can find an example of this in the [WebdriverIO examples](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/examples/pageobject/pageobjects).

Though, I will say that I have tried that route and I prefer a different approach. With WebdriverIO you can add custom commands to your webdriver client. So you can list your commands in an object :

```
 module.exports = {
     searchGoogle: function (searchString) {
         return this
            .url('http://www.google.com')
            .click('input[name="q"]')
            .keys(searchString)
            .pause(2000)
            .keys(['Enter']); //press Enter Key
     }
 };
```

And then you can bind those commands to the client:

```
var client = webdriverio.remote(options);
client.addCommand('searchGoogle',searchGoogle.bind(client));
```

Comment: exactly!! I am trying to implement PageObject pattern with WebdriverIO. I went through that example. Thank you!!! It will be nice if I have some working code sample.